# Set PYTHONPATH in SublimeText2

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I've been googling for the last hour trying to find an answer, and have tried everything I've come across.

I have a specific Python package (MailSnake) that, when I Build in SublimeText2, returns

**ImportError: No module named mailsnake**

I understand this is because SublimeText2 is running the builtin Python (version 2.6) and needs to have the PYTHONPATH set in user settings.

How do I correctly set the env path? This is what I currently have.

```
"path": "Users/Me/Library/Python/2.7",
"cmd": ["python2.7", "-u", "$file"],
"env":
{
    "PYTHONPATH": "Users/Me/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages"
},    
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit %APPDATA%\Sublime Text 2\Python\Python.sublime-build

Change content to:

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\python27\\python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

on mac

```
 { 
   "cmd": ["/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7", 
   "-u", "$file"], "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)", 
   "selector": "source.python"       
 }
```

after you've done that try the following

```
import platform
print platform.python_version()
```

if successful this will compile the code and prints out `2.7.* your current version *`
in my case this would be `2.7.2`

also, it looks like you may not have the mailsnake installed properly. so try the following

- [Download the zip](https://github.com/michaelhelmick/python-mailsnake)
- extract it into a folder
- using cmd, navigate to that folder and then into `python-mailsnake-master\python-mailsnake-master`.
- then in cmd type in `python setup.py install` and this should install
  mailsnake

  you should now be able to import it and use it

Comment: Hi - thanks for your answer, I'm trying it now. Just a quick question regarding the path "C:\\python...". Is that a Windows path? So if I'm on a Mac I'll convert it to my Python install, correct?

Comment: Thanks for your help cyberbemon. This is what ended up working for me. In Python.sublime-build, I used {
 "cmd": ["/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7", "-u", "$file"],
 "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
 "selector": "source.python"
}

Comment: glad it helped :), I'll add this to my answer !